# How to find the IP that is requesting my xmlrpc.php file wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress

I am using wordpress for a very high traffic website. The log of php5-fpm shows that xmlrpc.php file is executing too slow.

```
[03-May-2016 16:47:32] WARNING: [pool www] child 17754, script '/var/www/html/test/xmlrpc.php' (request: "POST /xmlrpc.php") executing too slow (10.292389 sec), logging
```

I disabled the xmlrpc function from functions.php file by adding a filter:

```
add_filter('xmlrpc_enabled', '__return_false');
```

But it doesn't work. The warning is still appearing. I think some bot or ip is hitting it. So, how can I find which IP is requesting the xmlrpc.php file so that I can disable it?

Comment: If you're using NGINX - in `nginx.conf` change the format to include `$http_x_forwarded_for - $remote_user [$time_local] `

Comment: Could you please elaborate that?

Comment: Be careful ! I got my wordpress hacked last week because of an xmlrpc exploit. You may add "Wordfence" plugin to protect your website, and see "real time trafic". I had a POST request on xmlrpc every 30 mins from random countries, and before protecting it, they managed to add advertisement content to my header...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look like there're no action hooks we can use when a client makes a request to `xmlrpc.php`. But we can use `wp-config.php`.

Try this in your `wp-config.php` file:

```
function wpse37002439_get_ip_address() {
  if ( !empty($_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP']) ) {
    $ip = $_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'];
  } elseif( !empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR']) ) {
    $ip = $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'];
  } else {
    $ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
  }
  return $ip;
}

if ( defined('XMLRPC_REQUEST') ) {
  $ip = wpse37002439_get_ip_address();
  $content = '[' . date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $_SERVER['REQUEST_TIME'])
             . '] [CAPTURED IP: ' . $ip . '] [REMOTE_ADDR: ' . $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] . "] \n";
  file_put_contents(__DIR__.'/wp-content/xmlrpc_access.log', $content, FILE_APPEND);
}
```

Make sure `xmlrpc_access.log` file is available. You can change it on your own.

I strongly recommend to take a look at [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3003145/how-to-get-the-client-ip-address-in-php).